# UILabel trouble

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, storyboard

I have a `UILabel` created in storyboard.

my.h file

```
@interface EditAndControll : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *deviceDetailLabel;

- (void)configureView;
@end
```

my.m file

```
@implementation EditAndControll
@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize deviceDetailLabel = _deviceDetailLabel;

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
}
}

- (void)configureView
{

    if (self.detailItem)
{
    DeviceCoreInfo *detailDevice = [DeviceCoreInfo alloc];
    detailDevice = self.detailItem;
    _deviceDetailLabel.text = detailDevice.deviceIP;
    self.deviceDetailLabel.text=detailDevice.deviceIP;
    NSLog(@"Device Label %@",_deviceDetailLabel);
    NSLog(@"self Device LaBel %@", self.deviceDetailLabel);
}
```

}

NSLog tell me that:

```
Device Label (null)

self Device LaBel (null)
```

All that i'm calling from main view:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController]      objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:selectedObject];
}
}
```

What am i do wrong? Please Help!

Comment: What does say an NSLog of detailDevice ?

Comment: Where are you calling [self configureView] from?

Comment: Also, the property for the UILabel IBOutlet should be (nonatomic, weak). Oh, and remove the synthesize calls, they're no longer needed if you're just using the standard calls.

Comment: DetailDevice is OK, 
configureView calling from EditAndControll method

Comment: Why did you write `DeviceCoreInfo *detailDevice = [DeviceCoreInfo alloc];`? You're leaking memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Check Form Where you call this `- (void)configureView` method.

You need To call that method as

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   // configureView method From here.
}
```

THanks

Comment: Seven hours of codding make blind my mind! U'll right!!Everybody right whis viewDidLoad calling!!!Thanks a lot!